# Can there be a bipartite graph that has an Eulerian circuit, Hamiltonian cycle, but is nonplanar?

Tags: graph-theory

So far I have that the graph's chromatic number is two (not sure how that would help) as well as that since it has an Eulerian circuit, all vertices must have even degree. I am thinking of using Kuratowski's theorem and showing it has no subgraphs homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ but I am unsure how to do that.

Should I start by showing since it is bipartite all of its subgraphs must be bipartite, hence cannot be homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$? Or would that be an incorrect approach? Thanks!

Comment: Have you made an attempt to find such a graph?

Comment: Yes, $K_{4,4}$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually yes and there are quite a few of them. How about, for each integer $n$ at least 2, the complete bipartite graph $K_{2n,2n}$ with $2n$ vertices on each side.

Note that $K_{3,3}$ is a subgraph of $K_{2n,2n}$ for all $n \ge 2$ and indeed $K_{3,3}$ is a subgraph of $K_{m,m}$ for all integers odd or even $m \ge 3$ .